# Augmentation and hooking into knockout bindng mechanism

Tags: performance, knockout.js

This is something I've been trying to do for quite some time. I've managed something, but I am pretty sure there is a better way.

**Question**

I want to be able to hook into the `bindingProvider` process to augment the **name** of the observable with a prefix (or something similar).

So if I have:

`<button data-bind="text: label"></button>`

I want to be able to intercept the processig of the binding and replace `label` with `myLabel`, so it essentially processed as:

`<button data-bind="text: myLabel"></button>`

and that is **based on some data on the ViewModel** that is being applied to the node.

**Attempts**

1. use `preprocessNode` and replace the `label` value with `myLabel` before KO gets to it

   Obviously, I'd like to avoid doing that, especially since `myLabel` may be used only in some cases - since it's based on dynamic data on the ViewModel.

   Also, no `bindingContext` reference is available, so I am not sure how to get to ViewModel.
2. Use custom `bindingProvider` and do some string/`$data` mash-up in `getBindings`
3. Use `preprocess` and augment the value

   This would be the perfect candidate if not for 2 things: I will have to repeat that for all bindings, since the form is `ko.bindingHandlers.<name>.preprocess` and **it doesn't give me `bindingContext`**, so I can't use that ViewModel data :)
4. Use extenders

   The problem with this is that I need that augmentation behaviour to be applied to **all** observable values, not just specific ones. By default.

**Any suggestions?**

Thank you.

**Example**

To further illustrate the requirement - imagine that I have a template that looks like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>,
        <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Trivial. Now imagine that ViewModel data looks like this:

```
{
    people: [
        {name: 'John', age: 30},
        {name: 'Dean', age: 40},
        {age: 0.2}
    ]
}
```

Basically, there are people and some of them are just born and don't have a name yet.
I'd like to be able to return something like 'noname' for those who are nameless and under the age of 1.

I clearly can do it by changing the template, but this is something I do not want to do. The template may be reused for something that prints `noname` based on gender, rather than age or something similar.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Currently, I think that you would have to go with a custom `bindingProvider` and do your work in the `getBindingAccessors` function. One approach might be to manipulate the node's binding string (by using the string and context) and then call the default binding providers function to parse the binding.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer Thanks Ryan. It's something I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Could you not achieve this with a computed observable? If you can't change the viewmodel objects (for whatever reason), you could perhaps change the bindings to bind to the return value from a global function, passing in the object and the property name to the function as parameters. I wrote a sample showing my thoughts which can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/QrV2y/. But I would probably suggest the computed observable, if possible.

Comment: @robert.westerlund Computed observable is problematic because the ViewModel is dynamic. You have a template with data bindings and you connect ViewModels to it - some have `text` property so the template works as is, and some have `description` property (or something else altogether) and have to be massaged into the template. The massaging is what I am trying to do by telling, on some configuration level, that `text` for this specific ViewModel, should be taken from `description` field instead. Quite confusing, but such is the reality.

Comment: @robert.westerlund I saw your example. Thank you. But that defeats the purpose of just writing `text` as name of observable and have it semantic. I guess there are two ways to go about it - semantic clean templates or semantic clean javascript. I prefer the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, observable are the way to go, thank you all who suggested it.

Eventually one of my colleagues had an idea that turned out to be a very nifty simple trick (and I was kicking myself for blacking out on this).

The idea is based on creating a `label` computed for `mylabel` observable. This would work in most cases, aside from the case when ViewModel **already has an unrelated `label` observable**, which will then be overridden by the computed - something that may not be desired.

For the ViewModel observable I want to map to (in the above example `myLabel`), instead of the original `label` you create a computed with the name of `label` (so that template still works as before), but a trick is to add the `label` observable **not to the ViewModel** itself, rather to an object that is **instantiated with ViewModel as prototype**.

Tha way - all the rest of elements to which this ViewModel is applied will use the `label` value that it has, and for this specific template the new `label` computed will **shadow the "old" one** - which is the desired effect.

Basically:

```
var Context = function() {
   // create computed observable `label` for observable `myLabel`
   // based on whatever ViewModel data is needed.
};

Context.prototype = ViewModel;

var context = new Context();

ko.applyBindings(context, node);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that would solve this particular use case is a custom binding which takes the property name as a string and sets the text to the given property using the `viewModel` parameter to the binding handler.

A binding like that could look like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customText = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var field = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())
        element.innerText = ko.unwrap(viewModel[field]);
    }
}
```

Here's a full [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daedalus28/wYfuQ/) example.

You could also do something more sophisticated than a straight property name lookup - you could even pass in a function to the binding which takes the view model as a parameter and returns the relevant data.

Comment: Thank you. This of course, is the trivial solution. Thing is, however, that I want to keep the standard binding. Otherwise it would just become an envelope for **all** bindings - this is needed for text, and if, and value and foreach....

Comment: Can you provide some more information on the specific kinds of things you'd like to do? Are you mapping sets of property names?

Comment: If just want to prepend variable names, you could wrap the dom nodes in parent element (virtual or otherwise) with a custom binding that works kind of like `with`. You could create a new binding context by iterating over the properties in the view model and making new ones available with your prefix prepended. The prefix could be a parameter to the binding.

The docs on creating child binding contexts might be helpful: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html

Comment: I think you are missing the point (or I do not explain it correctly). The template should be as if nothing of this exisists. I can't put **specical** comments or anything of the sort, as that would defeat the purpose of writing the template for a common case and matching the ViewModel to it at a later time. And it is much easier done using your initial answer. Also, see update (in a sec).